# How to add roles when user reacts to specific message

Tags: discord.js

I need it so that a bot will send a message and if anyone on the server reacts to that message with a reaction it will give them a role.

I Have already tried multiple times, different code samples which allow reactions anywhere in the guild but i want it specific to one channel.

```
client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {
  if (user.bot) return;
  const member = reaction.message.member
   switch (reaction.name) {
     case "":
     member.addRole("597011179545690121").then((res) => {
       reaction.message.channel.send(`You've been given the \`${res.name}\` role!`)
     }).catch(console.error);
     break;
     case "":
     member.addRole("597011179545690121").then((res) => {
       reaction.message.channel.send(`You've been given the \`${res.name}\` role!`)
     }).catch(console.error);
  };
})

client.on("messageReactionRemove", (reaction, user) => {
  if (user.bot) return;
  const member = reaction.message.member
  switch (reaction.name) {
case "emoji_name_1":
member.removeRole("roleID").then((res) => 
  reaction.message.channel.send(`You've been removed from the \`${res.name}\` role!`)
    }).catch(console.error);
    break;
    case "emoji_name_2":
    member.removeRole("someOtherRole").then((res) => {
      reaction.message.channel.send(`You've been removed from the \`${res.name}\` role!`)
    }).catch(console.error);
  };
})
```

I Want the outcome to be that the person reacts with say a smiley face and they get a certain role but they have to react to a certain message sent by the bot in its own dedicated channel same as pre-made bots such as Reaction Roles bot.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we have to fetch our Message.

```
let channel_id = "ChanelID of message"; 
let message_id = "ID of message";



client.on("ready", (reaction, user) => {

client.channels.get(channel_id).fetchMessage(message_id).then(m => {
        console.log("Cached reaction message.");
    }).catch(e => {
    console.error("Error loading message.");
    console.error(e);
    });
```

Then we'll check if someone reacted to our message and give them the appropriate Role

```
client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {
    if(reaction.emoji.id == "EMOJI ID HERE" && reaction.message.id === message_id) 
        {
            guild.fetchMember(user) // fetch the user that reacted
                .then((member) => 
                {
                    let role = (member.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "YOUR ROLE NAME HERE"));
                    member.addRole(role)
                    .then(() => 
                    {
                        console.log(`Added the role to ${member.displayName}`);
                    }
                    );
                });
        }
}
```

I advise against using this code for multiple Roles at once as that would be rather inefficient.

Comment: Why would it be inefficient?

Comment: You'd have to make a lot of if/else statements in a row which will grow larger and larger for every single Role.

Answer (score 0):

> ```js
> const member = reaction.message.member
> ```

**Problem:** This is defining `member` as the [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) that *sent* the message, not the one that added the reaction.

**Solution:** Use the [`Guild.member()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member) method, for example...

```js
const member = reaction.message.guild.member(user);
```

---

> ```js
> switch (reaction.name) {...}
> ```

**Problem:** `name` is a not a valid property of a [MessageReaction](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction).

**Solution:** What you're looking for is [`ReactionEmoji.name`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionEmoji), accessed via `reaction.emoji.name`.

---

> ...[the users] have to react to a certain message...

**Problem:** Your current code isn't checking anything about the message that's been reacted to. Therefore, it's triggered for any reaction.

**Solution:** Check the message ID to make sure it's the *exact one* you want. If you'd like to allow reactions on any message *within a certain channel*, check the message's channel ID.

Consider these examples:

```js
if (reaction.message.id !== "insert message ID here") return;
```

```js
if (reaction.message.channel.id !== "insert channel ID here") return;
```

---

**Problem:** The [`messageReactionAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) event is not emitted for reactions on uncached messages.

**Solution:** Use the `raw` event to fetch the required information and emit the event yourself, as shown [here](https://gist.github.com/Danktuary/27b3cef7ef6c42e2d3f5aff4779db8ba). Alternatively, use [Caltrop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11539618/caltrop)'s solution and fetch the message when the client is ready via [`TextChannel.fetchMessage()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel).